# Removing curse on me after I did bad

Tags: dua, islamic-basis, forgiveness, theft, curse

Assalamu slaikkum warahmathullahi wabarakathuhu.

Dear brothers and sisters, kindly help me. May Allah bless you all abundantly.

I am a 23 year old with a compulsive behaviour of stealing small amounts of money. Recently, one of a friend cursed whoever stole her money, and needless to say, that’s me. However, she didn’t know that. I was taken aback by this act and now I truly regret doing that. I promise to not steal anymore, and that I will be a better Muslim. I want to remove the curse that is inflicted on me. How do I do that? Kindly help.

Jazakallah khair

Answer (score 2):

It is a very simple 3 step process:

1. Return the money you stole from her, if possible apologize to her
2. Repent - ask Allah for forgiveness
3. Seek professional help for the compulsive behavior so that it does not happen again